# ReOrder Post Within Categories plugin with featured image

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails

I need to add featured image somewhere near title so I can easier sort them, currently the [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/reorder-post-within-categories/) use this code to show the title only, tried with the_post_thumbnail and nothing is showing up. Thank you.

```
            echo '<li id="'.$post->ID.'">';
            echo '<span class="title">'.$post->post_title.'</span>';
            echo '</li>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a plugin, it's probably going to get axed, but generally speaking in WordPress if you want to get a posts featured image and you have access to the post ID (which I'm assuming you do), you can always do this:

```
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );
```

So without looking at the plugin, it looks like you might be able to do something like this:

```
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );
echo '<li id="' . $post->ID . '">';
echo '<img src="' . $thumb_url . '" alt="" />';
echo '<span class="title">' . $post->post_title . '</span>';
echo '</li>';
```

Set your styles on the image accordingly (height/width/float/margins/etc.)

Comment: GENIUS!!! Is working! How can I send you a beer at least?

Comment: An accept/upvote will suffice. Glad it worked. Also, if you're not already aware... if you're modifying the plugin source, updating the plugin will wipe this out.